# pdfx and biblatex attempt to patch the same things?

Tags: biblatex, patching, pdfx

The below MWE gives errors.
Moving the line `\usepackage{pdfx}` below the biblatex package
(right before `\begin{document}`)
will currently not give explicit errors, but
“it is best if pdfx is the first package loaded” (pdfx manual p. 16).

What would be some ways to handle this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfx}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

test
\parencite{knuth:ct}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/846. I have no idea what `pdfx` is doing that things fail so spectacularly. Plus I'm not sure if it really is good advice to load `pdfx` as early as possible given that it loads `hyperref`... Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer found the problematic line in `pdfx` (see [her comment in the linked issue](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/846#issuecomment-447576326)). For now the workaround that stays closest to the requirements to load `pdfx` as early as possible is to only load the `ifthen` package before `pdfx`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it can be solved by updating pdfx to version 1.6.1 (2018/12/22).